# Is there a way to compile multi-threaded C++ program with single-threaded version library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, compilation, g++, clang++

I am trying to do a code auto-complile and auto-evaluaton program. I want to compare a program's efficiency difference in multi-threaded mode and single-threaded mode. So I am wonder that if there is a compiling option that allows me to compile a multi-threaded program with a psudo-multithread library (which uses actually single threaded implementation) to derive a single-threaded program from the multi-threaded one.

Comment: Just swap your thread pool out for a queuing, inline executor.

Comment: @KerrekSB Wouldn't that simple approach only work for threads that work independently? On the other hand, evaluating efficiency of single- vs. multithreaded programs would probably only make sense for programs that divide big problems into small, individual chunks for each thread to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you use for multi threading but 
you could use [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/) a shared memory multiprocessing API for that.

You have two ways of switching between multi-threaded mode and single-threaded mode :

- Disable/enable OpenMP with the `-fopenmp` flag in GCC and Clang.
- Use `OMP_NUM_THREADS=X` environment variable or directly use the routine `set_omp_num_threads(X)` where `X` is your thread numbers.

Note that there is a difference between the two ways they are not equivalent. I can detail this point if needed.